# I want to move the mouse pointer with an Arduino and ultrasonic sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

I want to move the mouse pointer with an Arduino and ultrasonic sensor but when I compiled it says

> Mouse.h not found

and I don't know what I can do.

Here is my code;

```
 #include <Mouse.h>

int echoPinCursor=2;
int trigPinCursor=3;

int echoPinBtn=4;
int trigPinBtn=5;
int echoPinScroll=6;
int trigPinScroll=7;
int x;
int y;
long duracionCursor, distanciaCursor;
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(trigPinCursor, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(echoPinCursor, INPUT);
 pinMode(trigPinBtn, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(echoPinBtn, INPUT);
 pinMode(trigPinScroll, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(echoPinScroll, INPUT);

}

void loop() {

    //mover el cursor
  int direccionx=moverx();
  int direcciony=movery();

  Mouse.move(direccionx, direcciony,0);
  delay(2);

}

int moverx(){
      distanciaCursor=obtener_distanciaCursor();
  if (distanciaCursor >= 1  || distanciaCursor <= 11){
       x--;
     }
   if (distanciaCursor >= 12 || distanciaCursor <= 24){
       x++;
      }
     return x;
}

int movery(){
      distanciaCursor=obtener_distanciaCursor();
     if (distanciaCursor >= 25 || distanciaCursor <= 37){
       y--;
       }
   if (distanciaCursor >= 38 || distanciaCursor <= 50){
       y++;
      }
  return y;
}

long obtener_distanciaCursor(void)
{
  digitalWrite(trigPinCursor, LOW);
 delayMicroseconds(2);

 digitalWrite(trigPinCursor, HIGH);
 delayMicroseconds(10);

 digitalWrite(trigPinCursor, LOW);
 duracionCursor = pulseIn(echoPinCursor, HIGH);

 distanciaCursor = duracionCursor/58.2;
return(distanciaCursor);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the Uno can't be a mouse.  For that you need the Leonardo or something else with a similar "U" style microcontroller.

If you are adventurous, and you have a genuine Arduino, you can reprogram the USB controller chip with new firmware so it thinks it's a mouse, but programming the main MCU is then a real chore.